# invoking member functions from producer thread

Tags: c++

Using a producer-consumer pattern I'd like to submit calls to the member functions of struct `A` i.e., `func_1()` and `func_2()` by passing the name of the function object (something like `A::func_1`), and a list of arguments taken by these functions in a queue-like buffer `queue_in`. I'd then like to collect these results (here a `std::variant` of all the possible return types (`double` and `int`)) in another buffer `queue_out` for later processing.

At the moment, I'm only able to hack my way by having `q_in` hold `std::string` and enumerating all the possibilities manually. Of course I'm also missing passing any possible arguments to `func_1()` and `func_2()`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "blockingconcurrentqueue.h" // https://github.com/cameron314/concurrentqueue
#include <variant>
```

```
using Result = std::variant<double, int>;
using queue_in = moodycamel::BlockingConcurrentQueue<std::string>;
using queue_out = moodycamel::BlockingConcurrentQueue<Result>;
```

```
struct A {

    explicit A(queue_in &q_in, queue_out &q_out) {
        std::thread t([&]() {
            for (;;) {
                std::string s;
                if (q_in.wait_dequeue_timed(s, -1)) {
                    if (s == "1")
                        q_out.enqueue(this->func_1());
                    else if (s == "2")
                        q_out.enqueue(this->func_2());
                }
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
            }
        });
        t.join();
    }

    double func_1() const { // func_1 might have arguments!
        std::cout << "func_1() called.\n";
        return 13.0f;
    }

    int func_2() const { // func_2 might have arguments!
        std::cout << "func_2() called.\n";
        return 1;
    }
};
```

```
void producer(queue_in &q_in, const size_t N) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i != N; ++i) {
        q_in.enqueue("1" /*..., arguments for func_1*/); // prefer to call the function-object instead
        q_in.enqueue("2" /*..., arguments for func_2*/);
    }
}

void result_consumer(queue_out &q_out) {
    for (;;) {
        Result r;
        if (q_out.wait_dequeue_timed(r, -1)) {
            std::visit([](auto &&arg) {
                std::cout << "The result is: " <<  arg << std::endl;
            }, r);
        }
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(0));
    }
}

int main() {
    const size_t N = 2;
    queue_in q_in;
    queue_out q_out;

    std::thread producer_thread(producer, std::ref(q_in), N);
    std::thread result_consumer_thread(result_consumer, std::ref(q_out));
    A a(q_in, q_out);
    producer_thread.join();
    result_consumer_thread.join();
}
```

How can I do this instead via function objects? Second, how do I invoke any possible arguments for the member functions of `A`. And third, can I avoid the use of a `std::variant` like result type?

Comment: The thread in A doesn´t make a lot of since you start and immediately join it. Could have been a normal function. Now questions. (1) What's the problem with putting function objects in the queue? If you know how to create a function object *and* how to use a queue, you have all the tools in your hands. (2) The function object stores the arguments. (3) std::variant looks like te most natural choice *given the problem statement*. Perhaps you want to change the problem statement itself. Why are the results of your computation can be of either type? What real world situation does it model?

Comment: BTW the function object could be just an `std::function<void()>` or perhaps `std::function<std::variant<int,double>()>`, depending on where you want to put the enqueue call.

Comment: Isn't `t.join()` redundant/never reached, since it follows an infinite loop on account of `for(;;)`? I do understand that it could have been a normal function given the limits of my toy example, but I'd like to accomplish that task (the ctor of `A`) in its own thread. To answer the enumerated questions: (1), (2) I don't quite know how to write the function object when I need to call the member functions whose instantiation is not known from the perspective of the `producer()`.  (3) Good to know that a `std::variant` is a reasonable choice for the return type.

Comment: (4) This a toy example. Indeed the API (for which `A` is an ersatz) I'm connecting to has several member functions with arbitrary function signatures. I was hoping to be able to skip the error prone task of manually writing switch statements based on a mapping to `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

Taking inspiration from @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. 's comments here's how I got the above to work using `std::function` and `std::bind`

```
using Result = std::variant<double, int>;
using FO = std::function<Result(void)>;
using queue_in = moodycamel::BlockingConcurrentQueue<FO>;
using queue_out = moodycamel::BlockingConcurrentQueue<Result>;
```

```
struct A {

    explicit A(queue_in &q_in, queue_out &q_out) {
        std::thread t([&]() {
            for (;;) {
                FO o;
                if (q_in.wait_dequeue_timed(o, -1)) {
                    q_out.enqueue(o());
                }
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
            }
        });
        t.detach();
    }

    void consumer() {
    }

    double func_1(double x, const size_t &s) const { // note the arguments
        std::cout << "func_1() called.\n";
        return x + s;
    }

    int func_2(int x) const { 
        std::cout << "func_2() called.\n";
        return x;
    }
};
```

```
void producer(const A& a, queue_in &q_in, const size_t N) { // note the first argument: the producer() must know about some instance of A
    for (size_t i = 0; i != N; ++i) {
        FO o;
        if (i % 2 == 0)
            o = std::bind(&A::func_1, a, double(i), size_t(10));
        else
            o = std::bind(&A::func_2, a, int(i));
        q_in.enqueue(o);
    }
}

void result_consumer(queue_out &q_out) {
    for (;;) {
        Result r;
        if (q_out.wait_dequeue_timed(r, -1)) {
            std::visit([&](auto &&arg) {
                std::cout << "The result is: " <<  arg << std::endl;
            }, r);
        }
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    }
}
```

```
int main() {
    const size_t N = 2;
    queue_in q_in;
    queue_out q_out;

    A a(q_in, q_out);
    std::thread producer_thread(producer, std::ref(a), std::ref(q_in), N);
    std::thread result_consumer_thread(result_consumer, std::ref(q_out));
    producer_thread.join();
    result_consumer_thread.join();
}
```

Output:

```
func_1() called.
The result is: 10
func_2() called.
The result is: 1
```